# how can we edit the top menu of Zen Cart?

Tags: templates, zen-cart

how can we edit the top menu of Zen Cart?
I have installed a template called pure_blue. I am getting the top menu as TOP_MENU_HOME TOP_MENU_NEW PRODUCTS etc I would like to change it to HOME NEW PRODUCTS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These defines are not in Zen Cart by default; they have been added by the Pure Blue template.  And since that template is not in the Free Software Add Ons, it's hard to know where they have used these.

If you search includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE for TOP_MENU_HOME, you'll see where these values are used.  If I had to guess, it would be

```
includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/common/tpl_header.php
```

but doing a search will tell you where for sure.